# How to find/delete a list of apps in iOS mobile device

Tags: ios, iphone

Our network has few mobile devices (iOS, Android based)

How to find the list of installed mobile apps in a iOS mobile device in my network, assuming I know the IDFA or IDFV.

How to delete a list of mobile apps from a remote machine or mobile device. Is this even possible?

Comment: you can't get list of installed apps or current running apps on an iPhone even on that phone as apple abounded it in ios8 but it was possible till ios7 and you are talking to control remotely simply not possible

Comment: This doesn't appear to a programming question.

Comment: I would like to control devices in a remote fashion. Is it possible?

Comment: You should look into commercial MDM packages

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you provide references to few MDM packages, I was able to spot only 1 vendor. Are there any open source solutions?

Comment: I don't know about open source, but major commercial vendors include AirWatch, Mobile Iron, Symantec and so on